# Proof that if $H \triangleleft G$ and $G/H$ is abelian, then $G' \le H$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I'd like some input on one part of my attempted proof for the following result.  The other part I feel good about.

"If $H \le G$ is any subgroup, show that $G' \le H$ if and only if $H \triangleleft G$ and $G/H$ is abelian."

$\Leftarrow$ Let $\pi:G \to G/H$ be the canonical homomorphism and let $aH=\pi(a), bH=\pi(b) \in G/H$.  Then since $G/H$ is abelian, $[\pi(a),\pi(b)]=1=\pi([a,b])$, which implies that $[a,b] \in H$ for all $a,b \in G$, so $G' \le H$.

($[\cdot\,,\cdot]$ denotes the commutator, and $G'$ the derived subgroup of $G$, to be clear)

The only thing that makes me a little uneasy is choosing elements $aH$ and $bH$ in $G/H$ like I did, since there could be more than one element representing them in $G$, but I think it still works.

Thanks.

Comment: So basically, you pick any two elements $a,b \in G$, and then show that $[a,b] \in H$. Looks good to me.

Comment: @AlexP.: Another Alex P.!  Good, thanks for the input.

Comment: Haha, what a coincidence! :-)

Comment: There's no issue with the fact that there are multiple representatives for $aH$ when defining $\pi(a) = aH$. For each $a$, the map $\pi$ gives you the coset containing $a$, and this is well defined: there is only one coset containing $a$. If you were to try to define a map in the reverse direction, e.g. $\phi(aH) = a$, that would be a problem as $aH$ has multiple representatives and you have chosen one in an arbitrary way, so $\phi$ is not well defined. **Edit:** just noticed that this is a necro question. Oh well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct.

You started, essentially, with $a, b\in H$, then showed that $[a, b]\in H$. This works because it shows that all the generators of $G'$ are in $H$ and $H\lhd G$.